# What is the easiest way to make a timed http.get request every 1 minute in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want this piece of code called every 1 minute.

```
var response = await http.get(url)
```

Tried:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) {
      response = await http.get(url);
    });
```

But comes up with:

Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.
response = await http.get(url);

The function inside which i am trying to implement these codes is async with type Future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions. Please convert the function to async like below:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) async{
      response = await http.get(url);
    });
```

Or, use the then in your future call like below:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) {
      http.get(url).then((result){
      response = result;
      });
    });
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the `await` in the second code.

Comment: Works perfect. Another query, when i add a DateTime.now() inside this Timer, it prints null everytime instead of the timestamp.

Comment: @Enzo, Thanks, it was a typing mistake.

Comment: @theguitarfreak, can you please show the block of the code?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is working fine. Although the first execution of the commands start after 1 minute. How can it be called to execute instantly on run and then every 1 minute?

Comment: The periodic timer calls periodically, so it is not possible to execute before the end of a period (here it is 1 second). If you really need to execute the API at 0th second, then please execute it outside of the function, then call the timer function.